# How does group-policy inheritance work for a Cisco ASA?

Tags: cisco, security, cisco-asa, firewall

I don't have a lab ASA to confirm this and reading through the Cisco docs left me less then %100 sure.

What I really want to know is if I pull an attribute from a group-policy will it then be replaced by what is already setup in the DfltGrpPolicy?

Here is a good example:

```
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 dns-server value 1.1.1.1

group-policy BLAH-VPN attributes
 dns-server value 5.5.5.5
```

if I then remove the dns-server statment from BLAH-VPN will that group then use the value set in DfltGrpPolicy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if I then remove the dns-server statment from BLAH-VPN will that group then use the value set in DfltGrpPolicy?

Yes, the `dns-server` value it inherits from `DfltGrpPolicy` takes over as long as `BLAH-VPN` is still defined